# Hyper-V fails to start with undescriptive error

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

So, first of all I enabled Hyper-V:

[image]

Ran the `winrm quickconfig` command:

[image]

And now trying to start the Quick-Create program results in (it crashes with this error on startup):

[image]

Usiong Hyper-V manager run as admin I receive this when trying to connect to local PC:

[image]

EDIT:

Running this from elevated command prompt changes nothing:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Following a little Googling, running the following from an admin control prompt fixed the issue immediately.

```
MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof
```

Comment: This made no difference.